# MVC5 Ajax.ActionLink in new Page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been search all around to figure out how to fix my problem but no luck.

1. I created a default MVC5 Web application.
2. In the Home(Index) view, I added the following:

   ```
   <div id="target">TEST</div>
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Test AJAX", "Ajax", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "target"});
   ```
3. In the HomeController, I added the following:

   ```
   public PartialViewResult Ajax()
   {
       return PartialView("Ajax", DateTime.Now.ToString());
   }
   ```
4. I created a new View called Ajax.cshtml that looks like this

   ```
   @model string
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Ajax";
   }

   <h2>Ajax</h2>
   <p>@Model</p>
   ```
5. The in the web config is set to true :

   `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>`
6. The following Bundle is rendered

   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`
7. My scripts folder looks like this:

[image]
In summary, All the custom stuff is adding the Ajax link, a new method in the home controller and a new view..

My Ajax Link also show the result in a new page instead of updating the target element.

Comment: Is jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js included in the jquery bundle?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895918/mvc5-ajax-beginform-and-the-correct-scripts-load-order/23897170#23897170) asks about AjaxForm but the answer is relevant here.