# Updating a div via Modal form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble updating a specific `div` on a form using AJAX. I'm using a modal form that allows the user to edit existing information and save their changes. Once the user clicks on a 'save' button, the modal should close and update the text on the form from which it was called.

Currently the changes are saved into my DB but the modal redirects with the HTML code fragment that contains the **new** information to `http://localhost:56544/client/UpdateClientDetails`.

I want to run the `UpdateClientDetails` action but stay on the current view (Index.cshtml).

I have been referring to [Apress's Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290) so far since I am new to these technologies.

**ClientController.cs**

```
public ActionResult EditClientDetails(int id)
{
    Client temp_client = _clientService.GetClientInfo(id);

    ViewBag.ProvinceList = PopulateProvinceList(temp_client.Province);

    return PartialView(temp_client);
}

public ActionResult UpdateClientDetails(Client newClientDetails)
{
    _clientService.UpdateClient(newClientDetails);
    return PartialView(newClientDetails);
}
```

---

**Index.cshtml View - desired `div` shown only**

```
<div class="panel-body" id="client-@id-info">
    <label>Client Id: @client.Id</label>
        <address>
            @client.Address1, @client.Address2<br>
            @client.City, @client.Province<br>
            @client.PostalCode<br>
            <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> @client.PhoneNumber
        </address>
    <div><button value="@id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-update-client">Change</button></div>
</div>
```

---

**UpdateClientDetails.cshtml View**

```
@using ProductManager.Models
@model Client

@Model.Address1, @Model.Address2<br>
@Model.City, @Model.Province<br>
@Model.PostalCode<br>
<abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> @Model.PhoneNumber
```

---

**EditClientDetails.cshtml**

```
@model Client
@using ProductManager.Models

@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    attributes.Add("class", "form-horizontal");
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "client-" + @Model.Id + "-info",
        Url = Url.Action("UpdateClientDetails")
    };
}

<div class="modal-header" id="EditClientDetails">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@Model.Name - ID: @Model.Id</h4>
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, ajaxOpts, attributes))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientAddress1" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Address 1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientAddress1-@Model.Id" name="Address1" value="@Model.Address1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientAddress2" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Address 2</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientAddress2-@Model.Id" name="Address2" value="@Model.Address2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientCity" class="col-xs-3 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientCity-@Model.Id" name="City" value="@Model.City">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientProvince" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Province</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Province, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProvinceList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "clientProvince-" + @Model.Id })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientPostalCode" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Postal Code</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientPostalCode-@Model.Id" name="PostalCode" value="@Model.PostalCode">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientPhoneNumber" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone #</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientPhoneNumber-@Model.Id" name="PhoneNumber" value="@Model.PhoneNumber">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="clientName-@Model.Id" name="Name" value="@Model.Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="clientID-@Model.Id" name="Id" value="@Model.Id">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Have you included the [necessary scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895918/mvc5-ajaxhelper-and-the-correct-scripts-load-order)?

Comment: @Jasen I believe I have. I have included so far:  `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` to `Web.config` (Found in the root of the project)  `<script src="∼/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js">` and `</script>
    <script src="∼/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>` in the `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file (in that exact order).

Comment: You don't need the `@` here `UpdateTargetId = "client-" + @Model.Id + "-info"`. What does it look like in the rendered form?

Comment: @Jasen Removed the @ sign. In the rendered modal form, the form tag that is generated looks like `<form action="/client/UpdateClientDetails" class="form-horizontal" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#client-2827-info" id="form0" method="post">`. That tag looks similar to an example my reference shows (`<form action="/People/GetPeopleData"data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#tableBody" id="form0" method="post">`).

Comment: But `data-ajax-update` is different.

Comment: @Jasen The `data-ajax-update` is supposed to be different. I should've been more specific. The generated form tag **structure** looks like it is similar to an example form tag in my reference. I am unsure why the modal is still redirecting.

Comment: If your redirecting it means that there is an issue with your scripts. Do you have any duplicates? e.g. if another copy of `query-{version}.js` is loaded after `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` then it would not work.